# How to create calculated columns (based on user input) on Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, streamlit

Please assist - new to pycharm/streamlit. I created a dataframe using pandas which has calculated columns. However, the dataframe is editable and the calculated columns use the user inputs. However, the columns don't calculate on streamlit/web app. I've added comments to describe what each line of code is meant to achieve

Please see below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(5))
dummy_df["col_a"] = pd.Series(dtype='float')  # column is empty - it should take a float input from user
dummy_df["col_b"] = ""  # column is empty - it should take user inputs
dropdown = ("A", "B")  # drop down values which user will select for column b (See next line)
dummy_df["col_b"] = (dummy_df['col_a'].astype("category").cat.remove_categories(
        dummy_df['col_a']).cat.add_categories(dropdown))
x = 0.5
y = 0.9
z = 0.3
```

'# The following function should do the following ->
'# if user selects option A from dropdown in col_b, then it should return a negative of the value in col_a
'# and if user selects option B in col_b then it should return the value of col_a as it is
'# The value from the two lines above (i.e. either negative or positive of col_a will be called current - see below
'# if current - (x+y+z) is positive then this function must return A, otherwise it must return B

```
def drop(series):
    if series.name == 'col_b':
        if series[series.values == "A"]:
            current = -1 * dummy_df['col_a']
        else:
            current = dummy_df['col_a']

        if current - (x + y + z) > 0:
            return "A"
        else:
            return "B"
```

'# This function is similar to the above but is used to calculate a value which is the sum of current and x,y and z please see below

```
def value(series):
    total = x + y + z
    if series.name == 'col_b':
        if series[series.values == "A"]:
            current = -1 * dummy_df['col_a']
        else:
            current = dummy_df['col_a']
        return current * (1 - total) - total
```

'# The following columns must return the values calculated from the functions defined above - i.e. they are based on user inputs

```
dummy_df['col_c'] = dummy_df.apply(drop, axis=1)
dummy_df['col_d'] = dummy_df.apply(value, axis=1)

st.experimental_data_editor(dummy_df, key='item_data')  # This is an experimental streamlit editor which allows users to input (i.e. for column a and b)
```